I want to update the live activity in my flutter app while the app is in terminated or background state
I am using live activity in my Flutter app, but I can't update it when the app is in the background or my mobile is locked. I tried using FCM to update the live activity, but I still can't update it.
I tried using Firebase FCM. but still it is not updating on background

What have you tried so far? I would suggest taking a look at the documentation here: https://pub.dev/packages/live_activities

I am already using the package. but i want it to update even the app is in background or the device is locked. The updating through push notification is not clear.

I don't think you can use FCM. Your server will need to communicate directly with Apple's server

Can you please help me on how to do it.
